# How to write Sparql query for the following result?

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, sparqlwrapper

[image][![SPARQL Query Details][2]][2]

How should I write SPARQL query to get the details from node2 : URI for node2 is same in both the graphs and URI for node 1 is different. Thank you in advance.

as such, I need below details.

```
node2 def
hasID ghi
hasvertex jkl
hasLastname mno
```

Comment: any tutorial would answer your question ... just use a triple pattern per edge in your graph and for anything you don't want to specify use a avialable. Then select which variables you need. that's the whole story of basic SPARQL in a nutshell. `select ?p ?o where {<node2_uri_here> ?p ?o }`

Comment: yeah i get that....But if I have similar two graphs where only URI of node1 is different and URI of node2 is same in both the graphs. I want to query in this condition. Can you please let me know how exactly to traverse in particular case. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking now, this doesn't match the image you show in the question. You asked for *"all details of node2"* which is exactly what my query does. So what's the problem now? Use `DISTINCT` operator if there are multiple nodes having an edge to node2: `select distinct ?p ?o where {<node2_uri_here> ?p ?o }`

Comment: I edited image and made it more clear now. Please suggest me a query for the expected result. That would be really helpful. Thank you. @UninformedUser

Answer (score 1):

To get all triples write `SELECT ?node2 ?p ?o WHERE {?node2 ?p ?o}`.

Now to restrict the results to graph 1 (defined by the URI of node1) you need to add `<http://ex/abc> hasName ?node2`.

Together:

```
SELECT ?node2 ?p ?o WHERE{
  <http://ex/abc> hasName ?node2 .
  ?node2 ?p ?o
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just alter that SPARQL slightly to use real URIs for properties:

```
SELECT ?node2 ?p ?o
WHERE {
  <http://ex/node1> <http://ex/hasName> ?node2 .
  ?node2 ?p ?o .
}
```